# if(){} else{} if(){} VS if(){} else if(){} in PWM control

Tags: pwm, timer, firmware

I'm using timer0 and a gpio pin to generate a 300Hz PWM signal on an ATmega2560.

The details if you care: F_CPU=16M, timer clock prescaler /256, count_max=208

The frequency changes depending on if I use an "if(){} else{} if(){}" or an "if(){} else if(){}".
The first generates 300Hz and the second generates 244Hz. Below is the code that generates the correct frequency. If I delete the curly brackets after the first two else's, I get 244Hz.

```
void pwm_on(uint8_t duty){
    if(TCNT0 <= duty){ //portion of counter active
        PORTB |= (1<<7); //turn on PB7
    } else {}
    if(TCNT0 >= duty){ //portion of counter inactive
        PORTB &= ~(1<<7);//turn off PB7
    } else {}
    if(TCNT0 >= COUNT_MAX){ //if counter full
        TCNT0=0;//reset counter
    } else {}
}//pwm_on
```

Why am I getting such a significant frequency change with code that doesn't change the functionality?

Also calling this function is the only thing I do in Main after initializing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a C syntax understanding problem and has nothing specifically to do with the hardware the code is running on.

Comment: @brhans I edited the title of the question to specify it is for PWM control since that seems to be the largest point of contention for moving this question to stackoverflow.  I am not a computer programmer and this is not a computer programming question. It is about how the syntax is affecting register level hardware timer0, NOT why doesn't this syntax work.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the end application is - your problem is that you're not understanding standard C syntax. You would have this same problem if you were writing similarly structured code to run on a PC. The fact that you're writing firmware for a micro is only relevant in how this problem is presenting itself - it's just the symptom.

Comment: Why aren't you using the perhipheral to generate the PWM for you? Which would allow you to dedicate zero CPU time to this task.

Comment: @brhans I have only been asking about the symptom, that being the change in frequency. My understanding shouldn't matter since the question has always been about the symptom.

Comment: @Attie when I figured out the answer to my question I started working on generating PWM with output compare match using pin OC0A which is conveniently the same pin that I am already controlling :) succeeded in generating a 300Hz signal today, now I'm figuring out how to control the duty cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why my frequency goes down and the period goes up with the "if(){} else if(){}" is because TCNT0 >= duty is always true when TCNT0 >= COUNT_MAX so the last statement that resets the counter at COUNT_MAX never runs so my counter overflows instead of resetting at a count that gets me a frequency of 300Hz.

I figured it out pretty quickly after posting, sorry if I am misusing this site, I'm posting a question on meta to see what the collective thinks so I can learn and use this resource as best as possible.

Comment: Posting of your own solution to a problem is encouraged.

Comment: if you compile without optimaziation i think you will get same frequency but much lower than 244Hz anyway. i find it wierd that you right else {}. check this out : http://cpp.sh/3rcrt

Comment: @Hasanalattar I'll need to research more on compiling before I'll understand this, but why I use else{} is because i learned misra-c standard in school and it was drilled into my brain that all if(){} statements must have its accompanying else{}.

Comment: Sidenote: To my understanding misra requires `else{}` only at the end of `if ... else if` constructs, and not on plain if statements.

Comment: @TammerTheHammer I tried looking for that MISRA rule, and as far as I can tell there is no such rule. There is one for chained if .. else if ... else if ... which sort of make sense but for a simple `if` there is no need for an empty `else`

Comment: thanks! I lost points on a lab in school for not having an else{} but I must not be remembering correctly as to the specific reason why. I stored away the extreme of "all if's must have an else" which i realize now is wrong.

Comment: the link i provided shows you that the second if is actually inside the else when you remove the curly brackets. in that situation the code in second if is not executed if its following the first if which was true. check the link in the previous link and run it..

Answer (score 5):

*This is more a code syntax question. Could be offtopic, might be moved to stackoverflow.*

`if(){} else{} if(){}` and `if(){} else if(){}` are different.
With correct indentation and brackets the issue is immediately visible:

`if(){} else{} if(){}`

```
if(condition){
  statement
}else{
  statement
}
if(condition){
  statement
}
```

And

`if(){} else if(){}`

```
if(condition){
  statement
}else{
  if(condition){
    statement
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm asking about the change in frequency (hardware) caused by the change in syntax (code) which is why I asked it here.

Comment: @TammerTheHammer Of course, but you should learn to use if-else-elseif statements to solve the puzzle. It's not the hardware, but your code.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The question/answer has to do with the timer count register which is firmware in any context. I was not asking "how do I use elseif statements", I was asking why is the hardware timer acting this way because of my use of elseif statements.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic / @TammerTheHammer you asked in the right stack. this has been discussed many times before and some people try to redirect others to stackOverflow while actually you should ask here for softwares related to programming microcontrollers

Comment: @TammerTheHammer Well, looking at the question tittle, people would think you are asking how to use if then statements.

Comment: @TammerTheHammer You haven't asked how to use if-else, but that's only because you don't realize it's the root of your problem. `code that doesn't change the functionality` - here it is.